# Redirect To Home Screen on iOs return

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

at the moment my android app always returns to the homescreen (RootPage) when it's launched back into the foreground.

The code to do that is as followed

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ...
    LoadApplication(new App());
    ...
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
    ...
    MainPage =  NavigationPageHelper.Create(new RootPage());
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to have the same behavior for iOs, such that when the application is returning back to foreground, it will always redirect to home screen. At the moment it stays on the screen it last stayed at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Form's Application subclass (`App`), you can use the `OnResume` override to handle that check:

Something like:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
    if (!(MainPage is RootPage)) // Assuming RootPage is what  NavigationPageHelper.Create assigns it in your App .ctor
    {
        MainPage = NavigationPageHelper.Create(new RootPage());
    }
}
```